# Create all possible matrix combinations without loops - Python

Tags: loops, matrix, combinations

I need to generate a matrix of 3 columns and 11 rows where in each position I can have either 0, 1 or 2. The problem is that if I introduce this in a loop, I will end up having 3^33 possible combinations, which I cannot save or even go through. What I want to to is to generate all of those matrices to operate with them in the minimum amount of time and avoiding that the Kernel dies.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Generate all of those matrices to operate with them in the minimum amount of time and avoiding that the Kernel dies.

Comment: Please update your question with that to make it clear.

Comment: Ok, no problem!

Comment: I was pretty sure my answer was OK :-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well each matrix has like 53 bits of data so your question is "how to generate all possible 53 bit integers" - log_2(3^33) < 53

If that doesn't sound alarming to you then I don't really know what to tell you but most of the time you don't have to have them in memory (or even on disk) AT ONCE.

If you're hard committed to generate all of them to have them in memory at once for some reason (and I can't really figure that out as even in integer format we're talking about 53 * 3^33 bits of data (quite possibly 64 * 3^33 as I'd use long integers but let use 53 bit integers) - that's ~3 * 10^17 bits, ~3.7 * 10^16 bytes, ~3.6 * 10^13 KiB, ~35122658018 MiB, ~34299470 GiB, ~33496 TiB, ~33 PiB.

33 PiB is A LOT of data. Unless you have NASDAQ quote or are federal agency (like NSA ;) ), you don't have access to hardware to process them at the same time.

Whatever you're trying to accomplish with this approach it's dead end. It sounds like you're facing a problem that brute force shouldn't be able to solve.